# Python pandas - how to access parameters of stats ols?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Using a Pandas dataframe and the stats ols method, Im able to run a regression using the code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.stats.api import ols
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [56, 55, 57, 58, 56, 58, 59, 60, 63, 62, 63, 65, 66, 68], "B": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]})
res = ols(y=df['A'], x=df[['B']])
```

However although this works

```
print res
```

Im trying to get just the fitted coefficient, and this does not work

```
print res.params
```

i get the error

```
AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'params'
```

how can I access the parameters, I am particularly looking the extract the coefficient of the regression, that is all I am interested in.

Comment: Has this changed? In pandas v0.22.0, `from pandas.stats.api import ols` fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
res.beta

B             0.945055
intercept    53.340659
dtype: float64
In [48]:
```

---

For just `B`

```
res.beta.B

0.945055
```

Comment: and how do i get just 0.945055 without all the rest of it?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use `dir(variable)` to see all of the members of an object.

For the `res` (class 'pandas.stats.ols.OLS') you'll see that there are members:

```
'beta', 'df', 'df_model', 'df_resid', 'f_stat', 'f_test', 'nobs', 'nw_lags', 'p_value', 'predict', 'r2', 'r2_adj', 'resid', 'rmse', 'sm_ols', 'std_err', 'summary', 'summary_as_matrix', 't_stat', 'var_beta', 'x', 'y', 'y_fitted', 'y_predict'
```

so you can do `res.beta` for example.  Which in turn has `'B'` and `'intercept'`. --> `res.beta.B`

BTW: leading "_" in the member name means private, and it's expected that you won't access those directly.  e.g. `_x_trans`